# Is there a way to create a pool of pools using the Python workerpool module?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool, pool

I am using the workerpool module to create some threads to perform HTTP GETS to a server.  I love the concept so far.  I set up a download job for a list of urls and then assign the work to a pool of threads.  So far so good...

```
import urllib3
import workerpool
from urllib3 import HTTPConnectionPool

headers = { }
headers['user-agent'] = 'Python-httplib2/0.7.4 (gzip)'
headers['accept-encoding'] = 'gzip, deflate'

class Download_Dashlet_Job(workerpool.Job):
  "This is a download dashlet Job object for downloading a given URL."
  def __init__(self, url):
    self.url = url
  def run(self):
    request = tcp_pool.request('GET', self.url, headers=headers)

#Create a pool of TCP connections for communication to the server (this is using urllib3)
tcp_pool = HTTPConnectionPool('M_Server3', port=8080, timeout=None, maxsize=3, block=True)

# Initialize a pool of three dashlet worker threads to be used for downloading from a page
dashlet_thread_worker_pool = workerpool.WorkerPool(size=3)

# urls.txt is just a text file with 5 urls in it
for url in open("urls.txt"):
  job = Download_Dashlet_Job(url.strip())
  dashlet_thread_worker_pool.put(job)

# Send shutdown jobs to all dashlet worker threads
dashlet_thread_worker_pool.shutdown()
dashlet_thread_worker_pool.wait()
```

The above code works well, but it only has a single pool of threads.  So, the case is ....

Single User opens Firefox to yahoo, and browser launches multiple threads to download components from the yahoo page.

What I would like to do now is this ...

Ten users open up their browser to yahoo, each user has his own set (ie pool) of threads to download from the yahoo page.

I'm stuck at this point.  Do I need to create a class object for the user, that object then calls the object Download_Dashlet_Job ?

I tried to do that but I totally goofed it up.  This shouldn't be very hard using workerpool, correct?

Comment: Why can the ten users not share the pool?  If you make it deep enough, they will all be able to swim.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  I can just add a lot of threads to the pool for these 10 users. I suppose my problem is really the tcp_pool.  The maxSize is 3 sockets, but I need that to be 3 sockets for each of the 10 users, not a global setting of 3 total.  How do I move the tcp_pool out of the "Job" to the "users"?